# proud in vs pride of

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions

For the following sentence, which one of "be the greatest proud in my life" and "be the greatest pride of my life" is more idiomatic?

> I believe being admitted into your university would be the greatest proud in my life

Comment: allen, you need to indicate what research you have done. Do you understand the difference between an adjective (proud) and a noun (pride)? Try again after you have googled the phrases **proud of** and **pride in** to see how they are used.

Comment: I know the difference between adj and noun. And I think my above sentence is correct for both adj and noun grammarly. I want to ask which one is more idiomatic, that is not shown in google.

Comment: [sentence above, not above sentence]. proud is only an adjective. idiomatic usage: make someone feel proud [adjective], give someone great pride [noun].

Comment: Ah I see where I get wrong. Then the second one [pride] is idiomatic and the first one [proud] is not correct in grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OP's context, ***proud*** is completely unacceptable. It *must* be ***pride***.

This particular use of ***pride** ("thing of which one is proud")* has declined massively over the past couple of centuries, but [here's a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20the%20*%20pride%20of&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#) showing the 10 most common adjectives used with it...

[image]

...and [here's another chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20the%20*%20pride%20of%2Cis%20the%20pride%20of&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#) showing just how rarely we include *any* adjectival modifier in constructions like *She's **the pride** of our family*...

[image]

I think the reason we tend to avoid modifiers (especially, *superlatives*) here is because this kind of "pride" already carries strong connotations of being uniquely highly valued. Consider the [still-common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=took%20pride%20of%20place&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) usage [***have/take pride of place***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-take-pride-of-place) - if you're at the very top, you can't be *more* at the top.